# is an "optionalized" pipe operator idiomatic F#

Tags: f#, pipeline, idioms

I like to use the pipe operator '|>' a lot. However, when mixing functions that return 'simple' values with functions that return 'Option-Typed-values', things become a bit messy e.g.:

```
// foo: int -> int*int
// bar: int*int -> bool
let f (x: string) = x |> int |> foo |> bar
```

works, but it might throw a 'System.FormatException:...'

Now assume I want to fix that by making the function 'int' give an optional result:

```
let intOption x = 
    match System.Int32.TryParse x with
    | (true, x) -> Some x
    | (false,_) -> None
```

Only problem now is that of course the function

```
let g x = x |> intOption |> foo |> bar
```

won't compile due to typing errors. Ok, simply define an 'optionalized' pipe:

```
let ( |= ) x f = 
   match x with
   | Some y -> Some (f y)
   | None -> None
```

now I can simply define:

```
let f x = x |> intOption |= foo |= bar
```

and everything works like a charme.

**OK, question: Is that idiomatic F#? Acceptable?  Bad style?**

Remark: Of course, given the right types the '|=' operator allows to split and merge 'pipelines' with options at will while only care about options where they matter:

```
x |> ...|> divisionOption |= (fun y -> y*y) |=...|>...
```

Comment: I don't see the need for this operator as you can use `|> Option.map f` - and indeed you can define you operator just as that ;) - and the best is with `|> Option.bind f` you get the monadic cases as well ;)

Comment: There is nothing particularly 'idiomatic' in using pipe operator except it sometimes helps type inference. Abusing it (and any other custom operators) could greatly reduce the code readability.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of Option.map. So I guess that answers all questions; there is a core library function of which my operator is more or less a special case, thus it is certainly better to use the inbuild function...thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think using Option.map would be more idiomatic:

> let g x = x |> intOption |> Option.map foo |> Option.map bar

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in my comment on Carsten's comment, I didn't think of 'Option.map' and it certainly resolves al questions asked...thx!

Answer (score 7):

There are two aspects not yet covered by other answers.

- Monadic operations for F#'s `Option` type
- Judicious use of custom operators instead of pipelining to standard functions can improve readability

Instead of a full-blown computation expression like `MaybeBuilder()`, we can define let-bound functions providing monadic operations for the `Option` type. Let's represent the *bind* operation by the operator `>>=`:

```
let (>>=) ma f = Option.bind f ma
// val ( >>= ) : ma:'a option -> f:('a -> 'b option) -> 'b option
let ``return`` = Some
// val return : arg0:'a -> 'a option
```

From this follows

```
let (>=>) f g a = f a >>= g
// val ( >=> ) : f:('a -> 'b option) -> g:('b -> 'c option) -> a:'a -> 'c option
let fmap f ma = ma >>= (``return`` << f)
// val fmap : f:('a -> 'b) -> ma:'a option -> 'b option
let join mma = mma >>= id
// val join : mma:'a option option -> 'a option
```

`fmap` is basically `Opion.map`; `join` un-nests a nested instance by one level, and composition by the Kleisli operator `>=>` is an alternative to pipelining.

In lightweight syntax, operators are exempted from increasing indentation with nested scope. This could be useful when stringing together lambda functions, allowing nesting while still indenting by at most one level.

```
a_option
|> Option.bind (fun a ->
    f a
    |> Option.bind (fun b ->
        g b 
        |> Option.bind ... ) )
```

vs

```
a_option
>>= fun a ->
    f a
>>= fun b ->
    g b
>>= ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `(|>)` seems to be an implementation of a very prominent concept of *threading a value through a chain of computations*. However, due to syntactic limitations of F# operators (precedence and left/right associativity) it may be somewhat difficult to use this concept in real-life projects. Namely:

- Whenever you use `Option.map` or `Option.bind`, it is hard to use code blocks. The code `intOption |> Option.map foo |> Option.map bar` would work great only if `foo` and `bar` are named functions;
- It is hard to keep lambdas small and separate;
- In any case, the code will be full of parentheses <sub>(which I dislike since my Lisp times :)</sub>

Using several small functions, the "chaining" approach lets writing a more succinct code.
**Note:** For real-life projects, I strongly recommend consulting with your team, because new operators or extension methods may appear counter-intuitive for the rest of your team.

---

Almost a real-life app code. Say, your app uses a command line parser which transforms this command line:

```
MyApp.exe -source foo -destination bar -loglevel debug
```

…into a `Map<string, string>` that contains key/value pairs.

Now, let's focus on processing `loglevel` parameter only and see how it is being processed by the code:

1. Filter the `Map` for `Key="loglevel"`; note, there may be zero elements;
2. But there may be also *several* elements, so we need to get the first one;
3. Then we parse out a sting value into your app-specific `enum` of `LogLevel` type. Note, parsing may fail;
4. Then we may, for example, arbitrarily override the value if debugger is attached;
5. But again, at this point there still may be `None` value. Let's place some default value;
6. Now we are sure that the value is `Some`, so just call `Option.get`.

Here's the code. Comments indicate steps from the list above:

```fsharp
let logLevel =
    "loglevel"
    |> args.TryFind                            // (1)
    |> Option.bind      ^<| Seq.tryPick Some   // (2)
    |> Option.bind      ^<| fun strLogLevel -> // (3)
        match System.Enum.TryParse(strLogLevel, true) with
        | true, v -> Some v
        | _ -> None
    |> Option.Or        ^<| fun _ ->           // (4)
        if System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
            then Some LogLevel.Debug
            else None
    |> Option.OrDefault ^<| fun _ ->           // (5)
        LogLevel.Verbose
    |> Option.get                              // (6)
```

Here we see how a key (`"loglevel"`) is being sequentially transformed through a chain of "optionalized" computations. Each lambda introduces its own alias for the value being transformed (for example, `strLogLevel`).

---

And here's the library to use:

```fsharp
// A high precedence, right associative backward pipe, more info here:
// http://tryfs.net/snippets/snippet-4o
let inline (^<|) f a = f a

/// <summary>Advanced operations on options.</summary>
type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option<'T> with
    // Attempts to return Some either from the original value or by calling lambda.
    // Lambda is required to return a monadic value (Option<'T>)
    static member Or f (x:Option<'T>) =
        match x with
        | None      -> f()
        | x         -> x

    // Same as above, but for lambdas returning plain types (e.g., `T)
    static member OrDefault f (x:Option<'T>) =
        match x with
        | None      -> f() |> Some
        | x         -> x
```

Answer (score 3):

`Option.map` / `Option.bind` is a really nice simple solution and I think if you have one or two chained functions, it's the preferable way of handling things.

I think it's worth adding that occasionally you could end up with fairly complicated nested Option behaviour, at which point, I think it's worth defining a `MaybeBuilder`.  A really simple example would be:

```
type MaybeBuilder() =
    member this.Bind(m, f) = 
        Option.bind f m
    member this.Return(x) = 
        Some x
    member this.ReturnFrom(x) = 
        x

let maybe = MaybeBuilder()
```

You can then use this in the syntax:

```
maybe {
   let! a = intOption x
   let! b = foo a
   let! c = bar b
   return c
}
```