# F# nested List.iter calls

Tags: loops, f#, iterator, nested

I have an F# function and I want to try varying some of the parameters and testing all such combinations. Is this the right approach? (The parentheses get a bit dense...):

```
let MyFunc a b c x y z = 
  ...
  q


let UploadResult a b c x y z q =
  ...
  ()


let a = 5.0
let b = 0
let c = System.DateTime.Today
let xList = [-1.0; 0.0; 1.0]
let yList = [2; 4; 6; 8; 10]
let zList = [0.1; 0.001]

xList  |> List.iter (fun x ->
(yList |> List.iter (fun y ->
(zList |> List.iter (fun z ->
MyFunc a b c x y z 
|> UploadResult a b c x y z ))) ))
|> ignore
```

So I want to upload 3x5x2=30 results, and write it nicely. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: what is the question or do you want just a code review? (in this case you might start by cleaning up a bit - for example `Let a = 5.0` will not work (syntax error)  and your indentation is way off

Comment: Well I've gotten ahead of myself a bit in posting before getting to try to run my draft because the application is quite big (the IDE isn't complaining at least). But I hoped to ask in general terms if nested List.iter would be the idiomatic approach (like I would write nested For loops in another language reflexively).

Comment: nested for loops would work too here ; what could be done is partially apply a,b and c in both function before the looping

Comment: Thanks. The above may be too obvious to bother asking. But often times being new to F# I'm surprised and impressed to see new clever approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your primary goal is creating a *Cross-Product* (or *Cartesian Product*) of several lists, and there are several options considered "good practice" among F# developers:

1. (removed `for`-comprehension as other answer already suggested this)

**2. Use Computation Expressions** (in the rest of Functional Programming world, it is often called *Monad*):

```
type Product () =
    member this.Bind (l,f) = List.collect f l    
    member this.Return n = [n]

let ret02 = Product() {
    let! x = xList
    let! y = yList
    let! z = zList
    MyFunc a b c x y z
    |> UploadResult a b c x y z
}
```

3. If you only **worry about parentheses**, use the *high precedence, right associative backward pipe*, ([more info](http://tryfs.net/snippets/snippet-4o))

```
let inline (^<|) f a = f a
```

Then, your code would need a minimal modification (albeit still not very clean):

```
let ret03 =
    xList  |> List.iter ^<| fun x ->
    yList  |> List.iter ^<| fun y ->
    zList  |> List.iter ^<| fun z ->
        MyFunc a b c x y z
        |> UploadResult a b c x y z
        |> ignore
```

Comment: Thanks much bytebuster. I'm very glad you mentioned computation expressions. I've been working through the tutorial on F# for Fun and Profit (and a little of Tomas's and Syme's paper too). I didn't see it at all but hoped that might tie in here. So I'm really glad for your #2 and I like how #3 tidies things up too.

Comment: Thanks also for the link in #3. The comparisons there help to understand how the operator obviates the parentheses. Very nice.

Comment: @RomnieEE I broadly use it in my projects. It lets me avoid parentheses in many cases. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33836770/974789) for some almost real-life code example.

Answer (score 4):

For purely imperative operations like uploading results, I would not really worry too much. Using `List.iter` as in your code sample does the trick. I would probably prefer `for` loop, just because then it is obvious that this piece of code has side-effect that matters:

```
for x in xList do
  for y in yList do
    for z in zList do
      MyFunc a b c x y z |> UploadResult a b c x y z
```

If you wanted to do something clever, you could write a function that produces all combination of parameters from two lists:

```
let product xl yl = 
  seq { for x in xl do
          for y in yl do
            yield x, y }
```

The nice thing is that you can also use it multiple times: `product xList (product yList zList)`. This gives you back a list of tuples that you can again iterate over:

```
for (x,y), z in product (product xList yList) zList do
    MyFunc a b c x y z 
    |> UploadResult a b c x y z
```

The not so nice thing about this is that you'll end up with nested tuples - which is why I'd probably go with just a plain loop. (Or if you always have exactly 3 lists, then the solution in the other answer, which is similar to `product`, but optimized for 3 lists)

Comment: Thanks Tomas for another of your insightful replies. I need to work through the details of the slightly different syntax in your "product" and Functional_S's "perm".

Answer (score 1):

```
let MyFunc a b c x y z = 
    42

let UploadResult a b c x y z q =
    printfn "%A %A %A %A %A %A %A" a b c x y z q

let a = 5.0
let b = 0
let c = System.DateTime.Today
let xList = [-1.0; 0.0; 1.0]
let yList = [2; 4; 6; 8; 10]
let zList = [0.1; 0.001]

let perm xs ys zs =
    [for x in xs do
        for y in ys do 
            for z in zs do
                yield x,y,z]
let f (x,y,z) = MyFunc a b c  x y z |> UploadResult a b c  x y z
perm xList yList zList |> List.iter f
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply F_S. I appreciate getting 3 useful answers already and it'll be hard to single one out. I automatically assumed that using a For loop would mean iterating by item, which I know is unidiomatic. Your usage is enlightening. Thanks again.