# F#: How to process a list of tuples?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm working on a homework assignment. And I'm trying to learn F# so I don't want any shortcuts besides using basic things like List.Map or lambdas or something.
I'm trying to process a list of tuples, but I'm having trouble accessing the tuples in the list. 
I want to take the list of tuples, add up the numbers in each tuple, and return that number, printing it out each time.

```
let listTup = [(2,3,4); (4,5,6); (6,7,8)]

let getSum (a,b,c) =
    a+b+c

let rec printSum tpList =
let total = 0
match tpList with
| [] -> total //return 0 if empty list
| hd::tl -> 
    print (getSum hd)
```

Comment: I have very well forgotten the syntax, would `match ... (x, y, z)::tl -> print (getSum x y z); printSum tl` work?

Comment: An advice: make sure all branches of match expressions evaluate to same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is map your tuples through the `getSum` function.  This can be done very simply by piping the list of tuples into `List.map getSum`.  Then you want to print each element in the list, so you pipe the result of `List.map getSum` into `List.iter` with the function `printfn "%d"`.  This works because of the functions having curried parameters.  `printfn "%d"` applies the `"%d"` parameter to `printfn` and returns a function taking an integer, which it then prints.  The whole thing would look like this:

```
let listTup = [(2,3,4); (4,5,6); (6,7,8)]

let getSum (a,b,c) =
    a + b + c

let printSum tpList =
    tpList |> List.map getSum |> List.iter (printfn "%d")
```

This prints:

```
9
15
21
```

We can even simplify the function further if we take advantage of function composition (the `>>` operator).  Notice that `printSum` takes `tpList` as its parameter, and then just uses it as input to two functions that are pipelined together.  Since pipelining just takes the output of one function and passes it as the last parameter of another function, all we really need to do is compose the function `List.map getSum`, which takes a list of `int` 3-tuples and returns a list of `int`s with `List.iter (printfn "%d")`, which takes a list of `int`s and returns unit.  That would look like this:

```
let printSum = List.map getSum >> List.iter (printfn "%d")
```

This will print the same results, but is a simpler way of expressing the function.

Answer (score 2):

F# has imperative loops as well.  In this case I think an imperative loop matches the problem most idiomatically.

```
let listTup = [(2,3,4); (4,5,6); (6,7,8)]
for a,b,c in listTup do
  let sum = a + b + c
  printfn "%d" sum
```

Comment: "imperative loop matches the problem most idiomatically" - in a functional language?

Comment: @Enigmativity Of course not: a functional language doesn't have imperative loops.  F# does, and I think they best match the problem at hand.

Comment: I almost always prefer tail-recursion or list-processing to looping in F#.  It's easier to enhance, refactor, or parallelize later, and in the case of list-processing, I think it puts the emphasis on the logic rather than the mechanism..

Comment: @Aaron the for loop style is one I adopted from Tomas Petricek a long time ago. Having worked full time in F# for four years now I still prefer it. I think imperative code should be written so that it is apparent. List.Iter always feels like you're sweeping the side effect under the rug to me. For loops make it obvious. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847782/171121

Comment: If we were simply printing a list, I might consider a loop.  However, because we are summing and then printing the list, I still prefer the list-processing syntax.  For example, consider the case where we get this code into our test environment and find out that the `getSum` over the list is too expensive, and we need to optimize it.  In the list processing version, we can simply change `printSum` to `let printSum = List.toArray >> Array.Parallel.map getSum >> Array.iter (printfn "%d")`.  In the loop version, it's a re-write.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I can't speak for you but I'm guessing we're both not telling the whole story. In prod code I think we'd both probably do `let sums = listTup |> List.map getSum` as its own step, because summing then printing is two unrelated things and seems a silly thing to wrap up all in a single expression even though F# makes it possible.  And I'd probably do that too.  Then whether you do the actual printing as a for loop or `List.iter` is just a matter of style, but it's a single line of code so no real difference.